# How to check for empty due date in the below calculated column formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am using below calculated column formula for group by:

```
=IF(Frequency="As Requested","G. As Requested",IF(DaysDifference<0,"A. Overdue",IF(DaysDifference<=7,"B. 7 Days",IF(DaysDifference<=15,"C. 15 Days",IF(DaysDifference<=30,"D. 30 Days",IF(DaysDifference<=60,"E. 60 Days","F. There After"))))))
```

it works great, i just need to add another IF condition to check for empty due date in the existing formula. Basically if Due Date is null then log 'Due date not populated'. Can someone help me with modifying formula accordingly, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([DUE DATE]),"Due date not populated",<<Your current calculated column formula>>)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, please change your answer, you are missing a parenthesis after [DUE DATE]), I will then mark it as an answer.